# Remove duplicates based on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to join multiple tables in a SQL Server database in order to use the fields in Report Builder. This SQL query is ran as a stored procedure. The problem is that it is returning multiple rows that I consider duplicates.

Here is my query (some structure parts were taken out):

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRollCallData] 
    @Ids        VARCHAR(255),
    @LexiconId  INT,
    @UUID       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @ReadOnly   INT
 AS


 DECLARE @TableCode INT
 SET @TableCode = 58


        EXEC InsertInSelectionCache @Ids, @UUID, @TableCode, 0

            SELECT [File].*, FileType2Lexicon.Label as FileTypeLabel, [People].DefaultPhone, CFV.Value as DOA, CFV.CustomRecordsetId
                FROM FileType2Lexicon, SelectionCache, [People], [File]
                INNER JOIN [CustomRecordSet]
                ON [CustomRecordset].RecordId = [File].Id
                INNER JOIN (SELECT Value, CustomFieldId, CustomRecordsetId FROM [CustomFieldValue]) CFV
                ON  [CustomRecordset].Id = CFV.CustomRecordsetId
                INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomFieldId, Label FROM [CustomField2Lexicon]) CF2L
                ON CF2L.CustomFieldId = CFV.CustomFieldId
                WHERE   [File].Id = SelectionCache.RecordId
                AND SelectionCache.UUID = @UUID
                AND SelectionCache.TableCode = @TableCode -- this is the code for File table  
                AND     [File].Id <> 0 
                AND     [File].FileTypeId = FileType2Lexicon.FileTypeId 
                AND     FileType2Lexicon.LexiconId = @LexiconId
                AND     [File].ClientIdString = [People].ClientIdString
                AND     CFV.Value <> ''
                AND     CF2L.Label = 'Date of Arrest'
```

This ends up returning:

```
Id  ShortFileNameMatterName Summary             FileTypeLabelDefaultPhone   DOA         CustomRecordsetId
4691    Bob State v.  Bob   RETAINED:1/1/2013   Criminal    (123) 242-8454  2013-01-16  6942
4691    Bob State v.  Bob   RETAINED:1/1/2013   Criminal    (123) 242-8454  2013-01-16  6948
```

As apparent, the rows are duplicating because of the recordsetId column. Each table row does have it's own UUID as well.

Any ideas? I've been working on this for days.

EDIT:
Here is my solution that I found.

```
    WITH RankedCTE AS(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [File].Id ORDER BY CustomRecordsetId DESC) AS RowNumber, [File].*, FileType2Lexicon.Label as FileTypeLabel, [People].DefaultPhone, [People].InvertedName, CFV.Value as DOA
            FROM FileType2Lexicon, SelectionCache, [People], [File]
            INNER JOIN [CustomRecordSet]
            ON [CustomRecordset].RecordId = [File].Id
            INNER JOIN (SELECT Value, CustomFieldId, CustomRecordsetId FROM [CustomFieldValue]) CFV
            ON  [CustomRecordset].Id = CFV.CustomRecordsetId
            INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomFieldId, Label FROM [CustomField2Lexicon]) CF2L
            ON CF2L.CustomFieldId = CFV.CustomFieldId
            WHERE   [File].Id = SelectionCache.RecordId
            AND SelectionCache.UUID = @UUID
            AND SelectionCache.TableCode = @TableCode -- this is the code for File table  
            AND     [File].Id <> 0 
            AND     [File].FileTypeId = FileType2Lexicon.FileTypeId 
            AND     FileType2Lexicon.LexiconId = @LexiconId
            AND     [File].ClientIdString = [People].ClientIdString
            AND     CFV.Value <> ''
            AND     (CF2L.Label = 'Date of Arrest')
        SELECT *
        FROM RankedCTE
        WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using either…

```
SELECT DISTINCT [FILE].*, (etc)
```

Or even a…

```
GROUP BY [FILE].id
```

Comment: DISTINCT doesn't work on the data types that are stored in the table. I tried casting them into the appropriate data types, but I could never get it to work. I actually came up with a solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To help the community on stack please post your answer so that others may learn from it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is `RecordSetId`, then group by the rest of the columns and use an aggregation column for that one.  Or, fix the problem by aggregating record set:

```
   SELECT [File].*, FileType2Lexicon.Label as FileTypeLabel, [People].DefaultPhone, CFV.Value as DOA, CFV.CustomRecordsetId
        FROM FileType2Lexicon, SelectionCache, [People], [File]
        INNER JOIN (select RecordId, max(id) as id
                    from [CustomRecordSet]
                    group by recordId
                   ) CustomRecordSet
        ON [CustomRecordset].RecordId = [File].Id
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Value, CustomFieldId, CustomRecordsetId FROM [CustomFieldValue]) CFV
        ON  [CustomRecordset].Id = CFV.CustomRecordsetId
        INNER JOIN (SELECT CustomFieldId, Label FROM [CustomField2Lexicon]) CF2L
        ON CF2L.CustomFieldId = CFV.CustomFieldId
        WHERE   [File].Id = SelectionCache.RecordId
        AND SelectionCache.UUID = @UUID
        AND SelectionCache.TableCode = @TableCode -- this is the code for File table  
        AND     [File].Id <> 0 
        AND     [File].FileTypeId = FileType2Lexicon.FileTypeId 
        AND     FileType2Lexicon.LexiconId = @LexiconId
        AND     [File].ClientIdString = [People].ClientIdString
        AND     CFV.Value <> ''
        AND     CF2L.Label = 'Date of Arrest'
```

This version arbitrarily chooses the maximum id.